# Nodejs app on Google Cloud App Engine not starting

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Good day,

my very basic Nodejs app is deployed on a Google Cloud App Engine instance is not starting. The app works locally, deployment with `app deploy` runs without error - and on the app instance the app runs successfully when started manually through Cloud shell (with `>npm start`).
However, as soon as the Cloud Shell is closed my app is dead. What am I missing? How do I start-up the app to run permanently?

The app consists of

- bot4.js file,
- npm dependencies
- app.yaml
- package.json

app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs8
handlers:
- url: /
  script: auto
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "blexplorer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "bot4.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node bot4.js"
  },
  "author": "oystersauce",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.4.2",
    "request": "^2.88.0"
  }
}
```

Again, the app is running fine when started through the Cloud Shell but no longer, as soon as the Cloud Shell is closed. Also, it's a super simple discord-bot - hence there is no front-end whatsoever.

EDIT: 
this is how I thought I started the app manually - but what I did here is starting the app within the cloud shell and not on the app instance: 
[image]

here is how I deploy the app: 
[image]

Comment: Something doesn't add up - cloud shell is normally not related to GAE, whatever GAE-related thing you do in cloud shell you should be able to do on your local machine as well. And starting a GAE app instance is not one of those things. So how exactly do you start your app "manually"?

Comment: @DanCornilescu thanks for your comment. I added a pic that shows it all. as I understood it "true-study-159312" is the name of my app instance. but it isn't? what am I starting then?

Comment: it just dawns on me that I am starting the app really in the cloud shell with files from my cloud storage - that is not the app. so it's no wonder the app is not running when I close the shell. Updating the question again.

Comment: Yup, you got it exactly right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From GAE perspective the cloud shell is simply a shell on a "local" development machine which just happens to be hosted in the cloud. The instance running the cloud shell has no special relationship with GAE whatsoever.

What you're doing when running `npm start` is not actually starting the GAE instance, you're just starting a "local" execution of your service, just like when you'd be doing the same on your local machine.

With your configuration GAE should start your app automatically as soon a request for it is received. On an app with a frontend just clicking on the link you circled in the snapshot would get you on it. Since yours doesn't have a frontend it would probably be just started, but you'd have to rely on the dashboard info and/or your app's logs to confirm it is running.